# Send feedback to spring from jbpm process

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, jbpm

My application is written in `Spring Framework 3.x.x.` In my application I want to integrate the `JBPM5.x` processes using its REST API. I have done this thing but I want to send feedback like simple message to my spring application so that I'm able to know what will be the status of my process on the exit of the process. I'm not able to find any way to send this kind of feedback using REST API.

Please give the right direction for it, or give any other way to integrate Spring and `JBPM` so that my Spring application and `JBPM` process can be run in different application container instances (same application server but two different instances).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the REST api would be capable of handling something like that, it is basically some stateless API to get / send information, but doesn't handle async notifications.

What I would recommend is registering a custom process listener to the engine that will be notified when a process is completed, at that point you can do whatever you want, like for example send a JMS message or any other type of async message that could be picked up by your application.

This information is probably already stored in the history log as well.  So if your Spring application could take advantage of that, that might be an option as well.